# Search multiple fields at once?

Tags: codeigniter

If I have fields in my database called `CarMake` and `CarColour`. What is happening is if I type in `Toyota` it returns all Toyota cars fine. If I type in `Blue` it returns all blue cars fine. If I type in `Blue Toyota` it seems to return all blue Toyota cars fine, but if I type in `Toyota Blue` it returns all Toyota cars but also any blue car, regardless of the make.

Here is what I have:

```
public function searchCars($data)
{
    $keywords = explode( ' ', $data);

    foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
    {
        $keyword = trim($keyword);
        $this->db->where("`CarMake` LIKE '%$keyword'");
        $this->db->or_where("`CareColour` LIKE '%$keyword'");
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('cars');
    return $query->result();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or where

```
$this->db->select( 'id,FirstName,Surname' );
$this->db->where('FirstName', $firstname);
$this->db->or_where('Surname', $surname);
$query = $this->db->get( 'namestable' );
```

more info: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.htm

edit ==========

if you want to do a like based search then try CI like

```
 foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
    {
        $keyword = trim($keyword);
        $this->db->or_like('CarMake', $keyword );
        $this->db->or_like('CareColour', $keyword );
    }
```

note there are **no quotes** around the $keyword variable.

Comment: Does this mean the search has to be exact i.e. case sensitive?

Comment: my understanding is that is first dependent on how your database is set up. if you are using phpmyadmin look on the page that lists all your tables, and look for a column called collation. if its like "latin1_swedish_ci" then the ci at the end stands for case insensitive.

Comment: I get undefined variable errors for the $firstname and $surname variables.

Comment: The main issue I have is I get results if I search `John`, I get results if I search `Smith` but I get nothing when I search for `John Smith`

Comment: hi - it definitely should work so it probably something simple - post your code so we can help.

Comment: Yeah like say for example I apply the example to cars. What's happening is say if I have a car called `Audi A4` and the color is listed as red. Searching for the word `red` shows all cars that are red, searching for `Audi` will show all Audi cars and searching for `A4` will show the A4 model, but I can't search for `Audi A4` or `red Audi`; it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Now I have the issue that typing in `blue toyota` returns all Toyota car models as well as all blue cars. I want it so that typing `blue toyota` or `toyota blue` only returns any Toyota cars that are blue.